# How can I output the lowest possible divisor using a while loop?

Tags: c

This assignment requires me to output the lowest possible divisor using a while loop. I think I have most of it down but I can't get the right output I'm looking for. I keep getting 0 as an output and I understand that it's the remainder from the mod but I don't know how to output something other than 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int divisor;
    int dividend;
    int lpd;
    int remainder;

    divisor=2;

    printf("Enter a number to divide: ");
    scanf("%d", &dividend);

    while(remainder!=0)
    {
        lpd=dividend%divisor;
        divisor++;
    }

    printf("%s %d","The lowest positive divisor is: ",lpd);
}
```

Comment: Nothing updates `remainder` and it doesn't have a value, it is undefined behavior. Probably most of the time it will have a value of `0` so the while loop doesn't run

Comment: @asimes can you give me an example on how to change my code around? I am still new to C and don't have a single clue what to do next.

Comment: Conner Miller "don't have a single clue" --> Sure you do.  Do not give up so easily. Try using a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: The lowest divisor of a positive integer *n* is 1. Do you mean you want your program to print the lowest prime divisor?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this...

```
int main(void)
{
    int divisor;
    int dividend;
    int lpd;
    int remainder;

    divisor=2;

    printf("Enter a number to divide: ");
    scanf("%d", &dividend);

    while(dividend%divisor!=0)
    {
        divisor++;
    }

    printf("%s %d","The lowest positive divisor is: ",divisor);
}
```

Comment: Hope the user does not enter `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int divisor = 2;
    int dividend;
    int remainder = 1; // Give this a non-zero value

    printf("Enter a number to divide: ");
    scanf("%d", &dividend);

    while (remainder != 0) {
        remainder = dividend % divisor; // Update remainder
        divisor++;
    }
    // Due to the way the loop is structured, divisor is off by one
    // Either subtract one or rewrite the loop a different way
    divisor--;

    printf("The lowest positive divisor is: %d\n", divisor);
    return 0;
}
```